# jQuery to get different value from on click class

Tags: html, jquery

I tried to get value from class have defined values

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="8">
```

and my jquery code

```
$('.cat').click(function(){
          var cat = Number($('.cat').val());
        $(".cat").val(cat);
 // after that using my code

}
```

Comment: try ` Number($(this).val());`

Comment: Number($(this).('.cat').val()); like that ?

Comment: itis not working

Comment: Why you use this?
 $(".cat").val(cat);
this line of code couse of problem
if you change  var cat = Number($('.cat').val()); to var cat = Number($(this).val()); it;s working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `$(".cat").val(cat);` and use `this` instead of '.cat' in selector

```
$('.cat').click(function(){
            var cat = Number($(this).val());
            // after that using my code
    });
```

```js
$(function(){
            $('.cat').click(function(){
                        var cat = Number($(this).val());
                console.log("cat value: " + cat);
                        // after that using my code
            });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="8">
```

Comment: its work but give to other checkbox sam value when I click on them

Comment: your code its working i think i have problam with code , thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cat').click(function(){
  console.log("selected cat number");
  $('.cat:checked').each(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
})
```

I Think the above code will help you, but not tried.

Comment: yes its working thank you , but i have like 30 checkbox for each one have difrnt  value .. .i take this part ' .cat:checked'  and working but give to the other checkboxes sam value

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `value_array.join()` for selected checkbox and give output into `<div id="out"></div>`

**Snippet Below**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '.radio-group input', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
      value = $this.val();

    // Get values of checked checkboxes
    var value_array = $('.radio-group input').filter(':checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    console.log(value_array);

    $('#out').html(value_array.join())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-group">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="5">
    <input type="checkbox" class="cat" value="8">
</div>

<div id="out"></div>
```